# How to keep relative position in a listbox when new items are added

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a databound listbox, and when i add new items to the top of the list, the scrollviewer maintains position, but the items i was looking at are pushed further down out of view.

Has anyone found a way to maintain the relative viewpoint as items are added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the vertical offset of the scrollviewer's scrollbar, add your items, then restore the offset?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try doing something with:

```
listBox1.ScrollIntoView(listBox1.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: There are 3 issues there. 1) It assumes i have a selected item. 2) It requires knowing what items are currently visible, 3) It would probably result in "jumping". I'm hoping for a seamless way to do this. Thanks for the suggestion though!